# encode array\list of images to video MP4 in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, encode, video-conversion

I'm building an app that encodes a stream of images or an array of images into MP4 video in Xamarin forms.
I couldn't find anything that works with xamarin forms and I've already tried these:

**1.** FFmpeg - (not working in xamarin native, require .netCore (I'm getting errors when installing any related NuGet package)
**2.** libvlc - I don't think it has any converting or encoding capabilities. 
**3.** searched in google, here and xamarin forum for a solution. 
**4.** skiasharp - apparently use only for drawing 2D and not for video encoding. 
**5.** Nreco - needs licence.
**6.** AviSharp/Aforge/Mediacodec/etc - Just for iOS\Android 
**7.** Encode MP4 from scrach - noticed that's too much work.

is there any way to do it without encoding the video on each platform-specific?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which platforms do you need to support?

Comment: Android and iOS (Xamarin.forms)

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed from your research, you simply can't bypass the platform specific layers while trying to do something like this. Technically, you could do almost everything on the core layer in C# with just the file loading and saving being platform specific but that would of course require writing the encoding code yourself.

I would probably go at it the following way:

**FFmpeg on Android**

1. Install the [Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder/) NuGet to your Android project (don't install to the core project at all). If this doesn't work, please comment what the exact error is.
2. Look at the [README.md](https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg) in the GitHub repository for a sample on how the library can be used to encode an mp4 file.
3. Use the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) in the core project to invoke video encoding code in the Android project.

**AVAssetWriter on iOS**

iOS has out-of-the-box support for creating, playing and editing mp4 (and other) video files, provided by the AVFoundation framework. It would make sense to use that since it's already well documented, tested and available as a core component (no hassle with licensing of open source libraries etc).

Again, you should implement the code on the iOS project and call it from the core using the DependencyService. There are plenty of samples on how to use AVAssetWriter to encode an mp4 file from a stream or a bunch of images.

Maybe take a look at the [PhotoFilter](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios8/PhotoFilter/PhotoFilterExtension/AVReaderWriter.cs#L134) sample from Xamarin if you want to see what different classes are involved in the encoding process.